# ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'GTID_PURGED'

Tags: mysql

I took backup of database from workbench from a remote server. So when I import it on my local environment I got error:

> ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'GTID_PURGED'

I'm using xampp server

Getting same error either import db via console or phpmyadmin

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After spending a lot of time.

I opened my database file in text editor and search for this variable "GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED". I just set it's value ""

like

```
SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED=""
```

Then I upload database via windows console now It works like a charm :)

Comment: I just commented out that line all together and worked fine.

Comment: i just removed that line and it worked :-)

Comment: where is located the database file... in xampp?? I'm facing this problem

Answer (score 37):

Need remove all lines with GTID_PURGED

```
sed -i '/@@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED=/d' your_file.sql
```

The final file will load without problems

Comment: It was handy to incorporate this into my database restore script

`pv db-dumps/mysql-backup.sql.gz | zcat | sed '/@@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED=/d' | mysql database_name`

Comment: additional variant use **-f**, example:

`mysql -f -u username -p database_name < file.sql`

Comment: Can you add a bit of info about when actually these GTID_PURGED lines are useful?

Comment: The edit queue is already full for this answer, but the `@@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED` value is often multi-line, so this solution as written may _not_ work as often as it does. A pattern like this would be required instead: `sed '/@@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED=/,/;$/d'`.

Comment: On MacOs you should use `sed -i.backup '/@@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED=/d' your_file.sql` (`-i` changes to `-i.backup`)

Answer (score 16):

Re-create the dump file by appending the `--set-gtid-purged=OFF` option would resolve the problem.

It was because `GTIDs` was added in MySQL 5.6, which is not recognized by the earlier versions.

Your command might look like below:

```
mysqldump -u username -ppassword -h mydbhost --set-gtid-purged=OFF db_name > dump_file.sql
```

More on my story, I got the same problem with a dump file originated from MySQL 5.7. I was trying the import the data into a new CentOS 7 installation with the default MariaDB installation, which is 5.5 (I guess).

The first idea came to my mind was to upgrade to latest MariaDB. Luckily their website provides [a great utility](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=globotech&distro=CentOS&distro_release=centos7-amd64--centos7&version=10.2) to help set the package repository for Linux variaties. Moreover, digitalocean has a very short and clear [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-do-i-upgrade-from-mariadb-5-5-to-10-1-on-centos7) for the upgrade process, thanks to them too!

While upgrading to the lastest MariaDB stable version 10.2 does NOT get rid of this problem. So I still have to use the option mentioned above, but it let me upgrade to the latest MariaDB anyway.

Another problem after my upgrading was that the `innodb_additional_mem_pool_size` config from `my-innodb-heavy-4G.cnf` is not supported anymore on the latest MariaDB, server failed to start. From the MySQL documentation, it was removed from MySQL 5.7. I can start the server after commenting it out. I'm not the DB expert, I would not spend more time to check how exactly MariaDB version mapping to MySQL DB, and what difference they have.

Comment: MariaDB doesn't seem at all interested in this option as even 10.4 will complain. This flag helps a lot.

Comment: Let me echo @tadman — I had the same issue exporting from MySQL to import into MariaDB (both at their respective latest dates). Your answer fixed the problem for me neatly! 

Comment: This command gives me `mysqldump: unknown variable 'set-gtid-purged=OFF'` 

Answer (score 6):

Kindly follow below step to resolve this.

1. Open your DB dump in notepad++/notepad
2. Search for **SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED=**"[some value will be here]"
3. Just remove this **[SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED=""]** line from the db dump
4. Save your DB dump and try to import now.

This is working for me and  I hope this will work for you as well .

Answer (score 4):

It may be tricky to load the file and edit it if this is a large database. Here is how I did it:

1. I located the line number with `less -N dump.sql`. It was at line 24.
2. Then I commented that line with `sed -i '24s/SET/\#SET/' dump.sql`.
3. Finally, the `mysql` command to import the database dump worked.

Answer (score 3):

You can also set the set-gtid-purged=OFF from MySQL workbench, before running the dump, click on advance options and change the AUTO to OFF under set-gtid-purged. run the dump and there should be no problem restoring to a different MySQL version.